# Squares, cubes, hypercubes added together

Tags: number-theory

This is related to Fermat's Last Theorem, at least to my intuition.

There are an infinite number of perfect square pairs that add to make a perfect square.
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

We know this doesn't work if the exponent is anything over $2$ (F.L.T.). But it turns out there are an infinite number of solutions to this:

$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3$$

and

$$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 = d^4$$

and (at least some solutions to)

$$a^5 + b^5 + c^5 + d^5 = e^5$$

I haven't found how many terms are required for the 6th power, but it is greater than $7$ if the sum is up to $100^6$. My exhaustive search program isn't especially efficient...

The question is how does the exponent relate to the minimum number of terms you need on the left side?

- 2 -> 2 terms
- 3 -> 3 terms
- 4 -> 3 terms (edited per comment below)
- 5 -> 4 terms (uncertain to be an infinite number of solutions)
- ...

Suppose there is an easy proof form this relationship and it holds for all exponents. Then that would be a proof for Fermat's Last Theorem. And it likely wouldn't fit within a margin, but also likely wouldn't be 100+ pages...

Comment: What is the relationship that you are expecting to hold?

Comment: For each power >=2 how many terms do you need on the left side to produce any solutions?

Comment: See [Euler's sum of powers conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_sum_of_powers_conjecture) and the [Lander, Parkin, and Selfridge conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture).

Answer (score 1):

In 1986, Noam Elkies found an infinite family of integer solutions to

$$
a^4+b^4+c^4=d^4
$$

The smallest is
$$
95800^4 + 217519^4 + 414560^4 = 422481^4
$$

So you in fact need only $3$ terms for the fourth-power case.

---

Elkies's family is a counterexample to a conjecture made by Euler in 1769, namely that if $n,k\ge 2$ and there exist integers $a_i,b$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^n=b^n
$$
then $n\le k$.  Fermat's Last Theorem is the special case $k=2$.  This is a bit like your conjecture, but without the 'infinitely many' condition.  The first counterexample found was
$$
27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5
$$
and there are two other counterexample known in the $n=5$ case:
$$
(−220)^5 + 5027^5 + 6237^5 + 14068^5 = 14132^5\\
55^5 + 3183^5 + 28969^5 + 85282^5 = 85359^5
$$

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. I only searched for sums up to 100^n, and when I found any I stopped...

Comment: @dashxdr 'naive' (i.e. unguided) searches aren't going to give much useful data here because there 'aren't enough numbers to go around' for small values of $a_i$ (to use this answer's notation).  If you're interested in doing this sort of search then you should learn about _sieving_ (and loosely related, the Chinese Remainder Theorem) first and foremost, as they're the most important ways to cut down on your search space.

Comment: You've got that right, my trivial program takes a long time to do the "exhaustive" search even within a small space. It won't scale well at all. I can't pursue this myself, but I was interested enough to explore the concept a little...